# Login from navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I'm working on the navigation drawer where i want to show details of the user in the navigation drawer like profile,contact us,logout etc if he is not logged in then i want to show only one item which is have be login on it nothing else must present in it i will be using the JSON for Authenticate the login Please refer the pics friends

[image: First image without Logged in]

[image: After logged In]

Comment: Voted to close, as this question is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is broad. However to achieve what you want, you will probably want to use the [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) library. Just check their README it's very simple to use.

The "login" functionality you are looking for will be in the `AccountHeader` of your drawer, for instance:

```
// Create the AccountHeader
AccountHeader headerResult = new AccountHeaderBuilder()
    .withActivity(this)
    .withHeaderBackground(R.drawable.header)
    .addProfiles(
        new ProfileDrawerItem().withName("Mike Penz").withEmail("mikepenz@gmail.com").withIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.profile))
    )
    .withOnAccountHeaderListener(new AccountHeader.OnAccountHeaderListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onProfileChanged(View view, IProfile profile, boolean currentProfile) {
            return false;
        }
    })
    .build();

//Now create your drawer and pass the AccountHeader.Result
new DrawerBuilder()
    .withAccountHeader(headerResult)
    //additional Drawer setup as shown above
    ...
    .build();
```

(Snippet taken from the official README, again: every thing is [there](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer)).

Comment: i also want to achieve it by using the JSONS

Comment: And that would be a completely separate matter then: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html I encourage you to edit your main question to provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is broad but if you are using navigation view you can change header view and drawer items using

```
        navigationView.inflateHeaderView(layoutResId);
        navigationView.inflateMenu(menuResId);
```

Navigation view is provided by android. So it is not a third party library and it is simple to integrate.

```
      <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- your content layout -->

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

You can find complete information here - http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html

Comment: my idea is to if(islogged ==true){navigationView.inflateHeaderView(layoutResId);
        navigationView.inflateMenu(menuResId);else{navigationView.inflateHeaderView(layoutResId);
        navigationView.inflateMenu(menuResId);}

Comment: yes of course, you have to check whether user is logged in or not